# How to process dataset to different frequency?

Tags: dataframe, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, data-processing

I built a model to predict user activity using accelerometer data and I used a dataset which samples where collected at 100 Hz. What can I do with this data to customize the model for predicting samples that will be collected at 5 Hz? Are there any good ways to regularize in this case?

I built the 1D CNN model using the keras library, I've load my data in dataframe,

Comment: I don't really understand your problem. The network structure shouldn't differ much when going from 100 to 5 Hz. Or did you train your model with the 100 Hz data and want to evaluate it on the 5 Hz data?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I train my model with the 100 Hz data and I want evaluate it on the 5 Hz, and I think this is a problem for model correct working.

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way to achieve this is to modify your training data if this is a possibility for you. Instead of taking the 100 Hz data directly, you just use every 20th frame of it. But you could perform some data augmentation by splitting the data into multiple sets by introducing a sample offset of 0 to 19. Otherwise, you have to modify your 5 Hz data by up-sampling it to 100 Hz. This would need some kind of interpolation between the data points which might be not that easy and introduces an error.